# JQuery mobile page transition without jQuery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am looking for a way to produce the jQuery mobile horizontal page transition effect on a mobile site without using the full JQuery lib. Does anyone know of a solution using a much smaller stripped down specific JS script? We are trying to keep file sizes to a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a decent solution to this.
Check out 'Non-Jquery Page Transitions lightweight' by fasw.

Demo here:
http://www.fasw.ws/demos/transitions1/slide1.html

And source here:
http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/

This is 1.7k of JS producing transitions that are just like those produced by the whole mobile jQuery Lib.

Comment: Will these transitions *override* jQueryMobile if I include both scripts? I am having trouble with the horribly shaky, blinky, flickery page and dialog transitions in jQM.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question; take a look at the accepted answer by Jasper on my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920730/jquery-mobile-css3-page-transitions-without-jquery-mobile-library).

You could also look at the decoupled widgets [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js).