# Trigger.io + backbone.js + zepto.js ... animations?

Tags: trigger.io

Are there any examples of android apps that have toolbars and simple animations? swipes, fades etc.

The ones i have found in google play don't have much in the way of mobile transitions.

The demo (wine box) is amazingly fast on my low spec android, i want to add a simple transition.

Comment: Check out this answer as I am also just thinking about using the the jQuery mobile Css transitions with zepto - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920730/jquery-mobile-css3-page-transitions-without-jquery-mobile-library

Answer (score 0):

We did a blog post about low-overhead basic transitions here: http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/09/05/simple-and-fast-css-page-transitions-in-your-hybrid-mobile-app/