# Slide divs on webpage like mobile home screens

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch

I'm building a mobile microsite that is to function like an app (with touch interaction).

I have a dropdown menu that has nearly full-screen divs which I want the user to be able to swipe between, like so:

---

[image] [image] [image]

---

I've included the jQuery Mobile library to get swipe events, which are working, but the divs are not sliding smoothly, and occasionally disappearing altogether, forcing me to refresh the page.

In the above picture example, on a swipe, div #1 would slide (hide) to the left fully, and *then* div #2 would slide (show) in the same direction, only after div #1 fully hid. I need the two events to happen simultaneously, so there isn't a gap between divs #1 and #2.

As for the disappearing problem, I have no idea what's causing that, sorry. Here is some relevant code...

**javascript:**

```
$('#menu').on('swipeleft', 'div', function(event) {
    $('#' + nextPage($(this).attr('id'),'l')).show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
    $(this).hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
});
$('#menu').on('swiperight', 'div', function(event) {
    $(this).hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
    $('#' + nextPage($(this).attr('id'),'r')).show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
});
```

If there's a better way to do this, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe look at where you've seen it, and copy what they did?

Comment: @leftclickben: If I could remember where I'd seen it, I wouldn't be asking here. Thanks though.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/widgets/transitions/

Comment: @MikeLewis: I'm not transitioning between pages though, I'm just showing/hiding divs on the same page (because I want other items on the page to remain static...in the pictures above, the blue div behind the menu, and the black bar with the up arrow remain in place as the divs slide between one another).

Comment: Try http://swipejs.com/  It looks like you can apply the slider to any html

Comment: Also, this could help.  Read through the answer, it appears as you can just use their CSS, and add/remove the classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920730/jquery-mobile-css3-page-transitions-without-jquery-mobile-library

Comment: @MikeLewis: Thanks, Swipe 2 (swipejs.com) looks promising. I have my div swiping, but only the first div is showing up (the others are blank pages). :) So I'll keep working at it.

Comment: @MikeLewis: Got it figured out. Had my subsequent divs hidden (`display: none`) with my previous solution, so I removed that code and got everything sliding! Thanks so much! You should post an answer below so I can accept it and give you proper credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**[SwipeJS](http://swipejs.com)**

or

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920730/jquery-mobile-css3-page-transitions-without-jquery-mobile-library) which describes how to use jquery mobile transitions outside of the normal usage.