# Jquery Mobile data-role="content" without using Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, pagination, css-transitions

I basically want to create the effect of parts of the DOM - divs etc - acting like single pages, like the data-role = content or page - but without using jquery or jqmobile as I find those frameworks too big and much too complicated for the simple tasks I require.  They also come heavily designed, that I dont want to use.

I saw these posts, but they are looking for similar transitions, not the basic functionality 
[JQuery mobile page transition without jQuery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919919/jquery-mobile-page-transition-without-jquery-mobile) 
[jQuery Mobile CSS3 Page Transitions without jQuery Mobile Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920730/jquery-mobile-css3-page-transitions-without-jquery-mobile-library)

But these posts lead me to believe there is a simple and light answer out there to mimic the functionality.  Can anyone suggest some Javascript, HTML5, or even a light framework that does this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about just having a [look at the JQM source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile)? That's the nice thing about open-source projects... ;-)

Sourcecode is pretty small, I am sure you'll be able to manually extract whatever fits your needs.

Comment: thanks - but my js skills are not that good!  My question was really does anyone know a framework out there where this is already done, so it saves everyone time.  Thanks