# How can I do a mobile page transition without using the full jquery mobile library?

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I know if I use jquery mobile then I will get the transition effect.

But I need only the page transition effect from jquery mobile.

So can you guys please tell me which css and script I should I  use to work for that transition?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919919/jquery-mobile-page-transition-without-jquery-mobile